# Copying the pixels of an image to a canvas in java

Tags: java, javafx

EDIT: I've changed some of my code to reflect what AlamasB said. I still don't understand how I should be populating my byte array and what conversions I need to do.

I'm trying to manipulate the pixels of an image uploaded by the user and write the new image onto a canvas. Right now I'm just trying to copy the original image without changing the RGB of the pixels. I've been stuck in the same spot for quite a while now and can't figure out where to go next. In the first section of the code I make a copy of the original image uploaded by the user.

```
   Image image = imageView.getImage();
   PixelReader pixelReader = image.getPixelReader();
   PixelFormat format = pixelReader.getPixelFormat();

   int width= (int)image.getWidth();
   int height = (int) image.getHeight();

   GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
   PixelWriter pw = gc.getPixelWriter();

   byte[] imageData = new byte[width * height * 4];
   imageData = createImageData(imageData, pixelReader, width, height); 

    //..        
    //...the next function populates my byte array with what's in the image 

  public byte[] createImageData(byte[] imageData, PixelReader pr, int width, int height){
    int i = 0;
    for(int y=0; y<height; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            int argb = pixelReader.getArgb(x, y);
            imageData[i] = (byte) argb;
            imageData[i+1] = (byte) argb;
            imageData[i+2] = (byte) argb;
            i+=3;
            pw.setArgb(x, y, argb);
        }
    }


    return imageData;
}
```

EDIT: No longer using this function. The next function is really confusing me. I'm referring to this http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/image_ops/jfxpub-image_ops.htm as a reference but I can't figure out what's going on.

```
//...  
//... the next function sets the pixels of the canvas to what's in the byte array

public void drawImageData(byte[] imageData, PixelWriter pw, int width, int height){
    boolean on = true;
    PixelFormat<ByteBuffer> pixelFormat = PixelFormat.getByteRgbInstance();
    for(int y = 50; y < 150; y+=height){
        for(int x = 50; x < 150; x+=width){
            if(on){
                pw.setPixels(x, y, width, height, pixelFormat, imageData, 0, width*3);
            }
            on = !on;
        }
        on=!on;
    }
}
```

Comment: So is the issue that the oracle method example isn't working or you want an explanation of how it works?

Comment: [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelWriter.html#setPixels(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20javafx.scene.image.PixelFormat,%20int[],%20int,%20int)) would be a good point to start reading. The method you provided doesn't create a copy of an image.

Comment: I'm glad you linked to the setPixels() method because that's what's been confusing me. It says the first two parameters are the x and y coordinate to write the data. Does it mean the x and y of the canvas or do I need to know the x and y position relative to my root object?

Comment: Which method are you referring to? Is it my create method or draw method?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `PixelReader` provides [getARGB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelReader.html#getArgb-int-int-) your best bet in this case is probably to use 32-bit representation. Subsequently converting it to a 4-byte array, i.e. `width * height * 4`. Finally use [setARGB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelWriter.html#setArgb-int-int-int-) to draw the image.

```
int argb = pixelReader.getArgb(x, y);
// populate imageData[i,i+1,i+2,i+3] by converting argb
...
// convert imageData[i,i+1,i+2,i+3] into a 32bit argb, say int argb2
pixelWriter.setArgb(x, y, argb2);
```

Alternatively, you can use Color's `getOpacity()` to get the `A` from `RGBA`. Again, using the 32-bit representation.

At the very least this will provide you with a minimal working example, which you can then extend.

Here's a quick version (self-contained, just copy and paste):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ImageManipulationApp extends Application {

    private static final int APP_W = 800;
    private static final int APP_H = 600;

    private Parent createContent() {
        Image image = makeMockImage();
        byte[] imageData = imageToData(image);

        byte[] modifiedImageData = modify(imageData);
        Image modifiedImage = dataToImage(modifiedImageData);

        HBox root = new HBox(25);
        root.getChildren().addAll(new ImageView(image), new ImageView(modifiedImage));

        return root;
    }

    private Image makeMockImage() {
        WritableImage image = new WritableImage(APP_W / 2, APP_H);
        PixelWriter writer = image.getPixelWriter();

        for (int y = 0; y < APP_H; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < APP_W / 2; x++) {
                writer.setColor(x, y, Math.random() < 0.00005 ? Color.YELLOW : Color.BLACK);
            }
        }

        return image;
    }

    /**
     * Modifies the pixel data.
     *
     * @param data original image data
     * @return modified image data
     */
    private byte[] modify(byte[] data) {
        // this is where changes happen
        return data;
    }

    private byte[] imageToData(Image image) {
        int width = (int) image.getWidth();
        int height = (int) image.getHeight();

        byte[] data = new byte[width * height * 4];

        int i = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
                int argb = image.getPixelReader().getArgb(x, y);

                byte[] pixelData = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(argb).array();

                data[i++] = pixelData[0];
                data[i++] = pixelData[1];
                data[i++] = pixelData[2];
                data[i++] = pixelData[3];
            }
        }

        return data;
    }

    private Image dataToImage(byte[] data) {
        // if we don't know the image size beforehand we can encode width and height
        // into image data too
        WritableImage image = new WritableImage(APP_W / 2, APP_H);
        PixelWriter writer = image.getPixelWriter();

        int i = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < APP_H; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < APP_W / 2; x++) {
                int argb = ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, i, i + 4)).getInt();

                writer.setArgb(x, y, argb);

                i += 4;
            }
        }

        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has helped me but I'm still confused. What is argb2 in your example? The documentation says getArgb() and setArgb() both use 32 bit format so what sort of conversions need to be done. I also don't understand how to populate the imageData byte array. I updated my OP if you want to take a look

Comment: In your example you populate `byte[]` with image data, I simply pointed out that you should be using 4 bytes to represent a pixel, not 3. If `argb` was your original unmodified pixel data, then `argb2` is modified pixel data. By conversion I meant converting a 32bit value into a 4byte array, again since you are using it as an intermediate format in your example.

Comment: Please see the answer, updated with a working example